Any VSCode plugin which can make back-link/wiki-link from comments in code to a markdown file?
There are some VSCode plugins which can make markdown files to run back-link/wiki-link.
I want to know, is there any VSCode plugin which can make back-link/wiki-link from comments in code to a markdown file and vice versa?
For example in a python file:
# main.py
# See: [[hello docs]]
def hello():
  print("hello")

The double bracket is wikilink. You can click the wikilink [[hello docs]] in VSCode (with option keybinding on macOS) to go to the hello-docs.md file in the same project/workspace.

What are you expecting as content in these files if they are auto generated?

have a look at the extension I made HTML Related Links (it is not for HTML only)
